# Good serialization format to use for REST API intended for iOS?

Tags: xml, ios, json, ipad, plist

Normally for REST APIs I'd use JSON as the output serialization format, but I'm wondering if that's still a great choice for iOS development (specifically, the iPad) given the more resource-constrained environment.

There are various JSON and XML libraries available for iOS, but are there some best practices for this, or reasons to go one way or the other?

Or would it be better to use XML in plist format, given that plist encoding/decoding looks like it's built into iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that only the binary plist format will give *any* performance advantages, and there are many disadvantages to using a binary format. Even then, the JSONKit library is several times faster than Apple's built-in binary plist parser. Here's the article that answered all my questions:

**[JSON versus PLIST, the Ultimate Showdown](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/)**

So I think I'll stick with JSON and probably go for JSONKit.

Answer (score 2):

iOS generally prefers [XML in a PLIST/Bundle format.](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle)

However, this is not particularly lightweight in nature, and is certainly not universally legible (should you decide to expand into non-Apple environments). JSON is still a great option for iOS, using the libraries like the [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) framework.

So it really depends on how tethered to iOS/Mac OS you'd like to be. Both options are reasobly simple to deal with.

Comment: Of course there are also plist libraries for other languages and platforms, and Core Foundation's plist-code is open-source.